# Playing audio using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play audio once the users clicks on a button using JavaScript. I'm looping through the database to get the audio files using PHP, but whenever I click on the play button it plays the first audio stored in the database, even though I clicked on other audio that are been looped and displayed it still plays the first audio in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
<div class="ms_weekly_wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <div class="ms_weekly_inner" id='player'>
      <?php
      require '../db.php';
      $sql = "select * from top15";
      $sql_query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
      $i = 1;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
        echo '<audio id="music_player">';
        echo "<source src='../Admin/Song/songAudio/" . $row['song_audio'] . "'/>";
        echo '</source>';
        echo '</audio>';
        echo ' <input type="image" src="images/play.png" onclick="play_aud()" id="play_button">';

        echo '<div class="ms_divider"></div>';
      }
      ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript responsible for playing the audio file

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    startplayer();
}, false);
var player;

function startplayer() {
    player = document.getElementById('music_player');
    player.controls = false;
}

function play_aud() {
    player.play();
}
```

This what I tried doing

```
   <audio id="<? php echo $audio_Id? >";
```

Then the JavaScript

```
   var id = "<? php echo $audio_Id? >"; 
   player =  document.getElementById(id);
```

But it's not working

Comment: You are giving all the audio elements the same id `<audio id="music_player">` and then using that single id when trying to play the audio `document.getElementById('music_player')`.  You need to give them unique ids and then reference the specific id of the element you want to play.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any additional code attempts.  As you can see, it is quite hard to read code in comments.

Comment: I tried giving the audio element id using the audio id stored in database  <audio id="<? php echo $audio_Id? >";
  Then in the JavaScript I did these.                               
 var id = "<? php echo $audio_Id? >";                    
 document.getElementById(id);                                            
                                                                                              but still it didn't work or even play.  What is my mistake

Comment: Waiting for response please

Comment: I asked you to put your new code _in the question_ not in comments.

Comment: Alright,  i have done that

Comment: Where is `$audio_Id` defined?  Why is there a `?`after it?  Instead of showing individual lines out of context, please show the entire code where they are used.  If you are still referencing a single element in your Javascript, then you are going to have the same problem.  Your play buttons need to tell your play logic which element to play.